# Conditional means across columns in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, average, aggregate-functions, mean

I have this dataframe:

```
year<-1990:2000
v1<-1:11
v2<-20:30
df1<-data.frame(year,v1, v2)
```

I want to calculate the means across the **all columns, but the first** based on conditions (in my case, on conditions put on the first column)

I want to do something like:

`colMeans(df1[,-1], condition is: year > 1992 $ year<1998)`

What is the most effective way in R to do this, if the number of columns are too large ?

Comment: What's is your expected output?

Comment: Obviously, the average of `v1` and `v2`, for particular years. In the example, the average between 1992 and 1998.

Comment: So what are the numbers then? Please add those to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `filter` and `summarise_at`

```r
library(tidyverse)

year <- 1990:2000
v1 <- 1:11
v2 <- 20:30
df1 <- data.frame(year, v1, v2)

df1 %>% 
  filter(year < 1998 & year > 1992) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("v")), funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
#>   v1 v2
#> 1  6 25
```

Or calculate `mean` for all columns then drop `year` column

```r
df1 %>% 
  filter(year < 1998 & year > 1992) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  select(-year)
```

Created on 2018-02-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you, but my column names might not necessary start with `v`. I named by columns as such for simplicity. In my real dataframe, column names do not necessary begin with the same letter.

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible in base `R`:

```
colMeans( df1[ df1$year %in% 1992:1998, -1 ] )
```